# VisualStudio ignores last folder in csproj

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Why last folder before $(FileName), e.g. "dummy removed by MSBuild" is totally ignored by Visual Studio when displaying files ?

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Protobuf files for ReSharper -->
    <Content Include="$(SolutionDir)packages\Google.Protobuf.Tools.*\tools\google\protobuf\**\*.proto">
      <Link>google\protobuf\dummy removed by MSBuild\$(FileName)</Link>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why last folder before $(FileName), e.g. "dummy removed by MSBuild" is totally ignored by Visual Studio when displaying files ?

Bold guess, you want to use `$(FileName)` to get the file name of those `.proto` files.

To accomplish this, you should use `%(Content.Filename)` instead of `$(FileName)`, so the code looks like:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(SolutionDir)packages\Google.Protobuf.Tools.*\tools\google\protobuf\**\*.proto">
      <Link>google\protobuf\dummy removed by MSBuild\%(Content.Filename)</Link>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

With above code, those `.proto` files are display in the solution explorer under the **dummy removed by MSBuild** folder:

[image]

Hope this helps.